# Send message using telegram bot with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm doing a service to warn me of possible errors that can occur on my server , my doubt is , after I send a message as I finalize the execution or the way it is presenting the image below normal? For to complete the task I have to take a ctrl + c

code:

```
var util = require('util');

var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

var token = '237907874:AAG8hK1lPWi1WRlqQT2';

var bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

var millisecondsToWait = 5000;

robot = {
    "alert": function teste(message) {
        var toId = '-103822200';
        var resp = util.format('alerta: %s', message);
        bot.sendMessage(toId, resp);
    }
}

robot.alert(process.argv[2]);
```

in cmd i execute this code

```
node.exe bot.js 'text send'
```

[this is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Hoo.jpg)

Comment: This error tells that your bot has web hook which is not responding on port 443. Does you configure web hook option?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some error occurs but not captured:

```
var robot = { // Don't forget about var :)
    "alert": function teste(message) {
        var toId = '-103822200';
        var resp = util.format('alerta: %s', message);
        bot.sendMessage(toId, resp)
        .catch(function(error){ // Catch possible error
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
}
```